# How can I verify if a function was defined in JavaScript?

Tags: javascript

How can I verify if a function was defined already?

Will this work?

```
if(window.opener.MyFunctionBlah) {  ...  }
```

Answer (score 6):

```
if (typeof yourFunctionName === 'function') {
    yourFunctionName();
}
```

Comment: If i remember correctly, (typeof function(){}) is 'object' in IE.

Comment: Nope, it's "function" as well. I think you're thinking of typeof for arrays.

Comment: In this specific case it may be "if (window.opener && typeof window.opener.MyFunctionBlah == 'function')".
You can't expect window.opener to be always an object...

Comment: In the case of `window.opener` even if `MyFunctionBlar` is a `function`. In IE `typeof window.opener.MyFunctionBlar` will be `object`.

Answer (score 2):

Yes. Functions are just properties of objects like any other, so you can treat them as such. The conditional you posted above will return true if that function (or any member of `window.opener` called `MyFunctionBlah`) is defined and non-null.

Comment: Technically, non-null, non-false, non-zero, and non-empty-string... but hopefully, any name that looks like a function would actually be a function if it exists.